# caffe TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, caffe

When I use the code at the URL below to make a prediction, I’m getting an error:

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Using-a-Trained-Network:-Deploy

Here is the code:

```
import caffe
from cv2 import imread

model = 'lenet_train_test.prototxt'
weights = 'lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel'
net  = caffe.Net(model,weights,'test')
image = imread('test1.png')
res = net.forward({image})
```

Here is the error I’m getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Happened when I do {image}

Comment: Seems incorrect to me. And I have no idea what that `res{1}` on the next line even is.

Comment: What happens if you replace {image} with image? What that error is telling you is that the curly brackets define a set, but all the elements of a set must be hashable (in particular immutable) and a numpy array from an imread is not.

Comment: >>> net.forward(image)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zhe/Downloads/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 119, in _Net_forward
    outputs = set(self.outputs + blobs)
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their are many example in internets. I bring one of them.

```
image = np.array(Image.open('sample/image/yours.jpg'))
im_input = im[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]

net.blobs['data'].reshape(*im_input.shape)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = im_input

output = net.forward()
```

this way is more popular way when inferencing result from caffe model.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,I changed my code and it works